# What do you call an elementary, middle and high schools sharing the same space?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I used to go to a school where the primary (elementary) and secondary (middle+high) schools both share the same area. So basically as a secondary schooler, I could walk to the primary side without ever leaving the gated school grounds.

The adjective in Malay is "Kompleks" which directly translates to "complex" but I don't think the term "complex secondary school" is a thing.

Comment: In the US, a school that combines elementary and middle school is usually called a "K-8 school," since it enrolls students from Kindergarten through Grade 8. In theory, if one also included a high school it would be called a "K-12 school," but from a Google search it seems that the term isn't used with this meaning, because such schools generally don't exist in the US.

Comment: In any event, you'd need to specify *where* you plan on using this term, since terms for various kinds of schools differ greatly between, say,  the US and the UK.

Comment: In the US, these are called “K–12” schools (kindergarten + grades 1–12).

Comment: @alphabet  — And they do indeed exist.

Comment: To share a space is to [colocate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/colocate) and it's often used for schools.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-through_school) this is an **all-through school**. "All-through schools educate young people throughout multiple stages of their education, generally throughout childhood and adolescence." This appears to be mainly a British term.

**K–12** (as mentioned in comments by alphabet and Tinfoil Hat) is often used in the US and Canada to refer to the full range of education from kindergarten to grade 12 (the final grade before graduating high school) - this is normally performed over multiple institutions. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%E2%80%9312) refers to **unified K–12 schools** as offering the full range, generally only found in rural areas where there are insufficient pupils to justify separate institutions. (Many variants such as P-12 also exist, with varying meanings.)

Comment: This is similar to, but not quite the same as, what the OP describes. Referring to something as a unified K-12 school implies that is a single institution, while the question is about the arrangements in which institutionally distinct school**s** share the same physical facilities.